# IdleTimer is not a function

Tags: jquery, typescript, idle-timer

when i use this function on my project:

```
$(function()    {
      // Set idle time
      $(this).idleTimer(2500);
});
```

compare this error:

`$(...).idleTimer is not a function`

with this libraries:

```
"inspinia.js",
"pace.min.js",
"idle-timer.min.js",
"toastr.min.js"
```

How can i do for include idleTimer?

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i resolved!
I changed the order into my folder that contains all libraries in this way:

```
"inspinia.js",
"idle-timer.min.js",
"pace.min.js",
"toastr.min.js"
```